# Disable F12, Right Click, CTRL+U and CTRL+S using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would disable some buttons on my HTML test page, (<kbd>F12</kbd>, Right-click and,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>).

My code is:

```
document.onkeypress = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    return keyFunction(event);
}
document.onmousedown = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    return keyFunction(event);
}
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    return keyFunction(event);
}

//Disable right click script 
var message="Sorry, right-click has been disabled"; 

function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}} 
function clickNS(e) {if 
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) { 
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}} 
if (document.layers) 
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;} 
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;} 
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")

function keyFunction(event){
    //"F12" key
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
        return false;
    }

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
        return false;
    }
    //"J" key
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 74) {
        return false;
    }
    //"S" key
    if (event.keyCode == 83) {
       return false;
    }
    //"U" key
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 85) {
       return false;
    }
    //F5
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Note: I have included this JavaScript function to few JSP only. My requirement is disable <kbd>F12</kbd>, right-click for some JSP pages only, not all.

Problem:

When I run this code for particular page (xxx.jsp) it's working fine. But I open another page (yyy.JPS) in my application, press <kbd>F12</kbd> and the inspect element appears in the browser. Now if I navigate back to xxx.jsp I can see the inspect element. Is it possible to disable the inspect element if it's already open?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why are you trying to prevent the user from operating their browser application?

Comment: our security team found some issues

Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS),
Parameter Tampering,
Request Forging

I already fix all issues in server side but additional i want disable browser side also but i dodnt know this is correct way or not
can you guide me and give me good approach

Comment: So you're trying to stop them from doing that?

Comment: You can intercept a key stroke on a specific page and make it non-functional but you cannot force close the developer console once it is already open, nor could you prevent the user from accessing the developer console via the browser's menu, etc. If you explain why you want to do this, we might be able to offer alternatives.

Comment: so what? then they change some values in the dev-tools rather then through the UI. Do you mean that this is actually a line of defense against invalid/modified inputs to the backend?